# Remove button borders - nativescript

Tags: android, css, nativescript

I am trying to remove borders of register button

```
#register{
   background-color: transparent;
   border-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
   border-width: 0;
}
```

`border` property seems like is not support in nativescript styling [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#supported-properties) and when I use `border-radius: 1` border is despairing.

Platform: android (5.0.2) and {N} 1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested a button with your styles and borders are removed with no problem.
Can you specify on what platform and {N} version you are encountering this issue!?
Styling background-color of Button will remove the default material design styles as described [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1296) and anti-aliasing borders were fixed with version 1.7.0 of {N} so border-radius: 1 should be working as espected.

In CSS the following code

```
border : 0 solid black
```

is identical to the following in {N} and CSS as well

```
 border-width : 0 
 border-color: black;
```

(by default border is of type **solid**)

So you can apply button styles without using the shorthand (border: 0 solid black;)

Comment: Platform: android device (5.0.2) & {N} version: 1.7.1

Answer (score 3):

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0);
border-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0);
border-width: 1;
```

Above is the new way to resolve this issue as of June 2017. Credit tsonevn.

See https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2626

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try something like this.

```
.btn-nostyle {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0,
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe `border-width:0` is a better solution.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Thanks that was the update to that snippet.

Comment: But it makes no sense to have both the width set to zero and the color to transparent, why would you set color for something that is not visible anyway?

Comment: But how do you know I'm a bro?:))

Comment: Lucky guess, but i would be damn if u're not.

Comment: You have a syntax error at border-width.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @Delino has mentioned has a point.

Border and background-color for Button in NativeScript are dependent on the zIndex of the button. So I believe, to remove the border, we have to specify the Index.

```
border-width: 0;
border-color: black;
z-index: 0;
```

If need to change or remove the background do the same by using zIndex.